# How to assigned specific "comment" view mode for specific "node" view mode?

Tags: nodes, hooks, comments

In "Article" content type i have three view mode in "Manage Display" namely "teaser", "default" and "abc".

Similary in "Comment Display" i have two view mode namely "defalut" and "xyz".

Eg: When i see "abc" node page where i am listing comments, that time the comment should be display with my "xyz" view mode not the "default" one.

function custom_node_view($node) {
    return node_view($node, 'abc');
}

Comment: @Rupesh kindly check the updated info and do the needful

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_entity_view_mode_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7) to switch it on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, currently i am using this hook only, i am looking is their any better solutions for this.